# how to enable self-defined python script for gdb in launch.json of vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger

As we all know, gdb is useful for debugging cpp, we can use gdb in vscode by configure launch.json. When you want to run python script for gdb, you can start the gdb in console and type "source xx.py". However, in vscode, you can only configure the gdb in launch.json before the target program start. So I want know how to configure the launch.json file to configure the self-defined python for gdb to be configured.(Because my project is cmake project, so i want to debug it through launch.json)

Answer (score -1):

[image]
Note and modify:

1. program: program name to debug (including path, preferably absolute path)
2. miDebuggerServerAddress: address and port of the server
3. cwd: path to debugger
4. miDebuggerPath: path to GDB